# Evaluating $\int \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}} \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to get some advice how to evaluate the integral,

$$\int \frac{\sin^2{x}}{\sqrt{\cos{x}}} \mathrm dx$$

Comment: This question is not trivial!

Comment: not at all trivial : http://goo.gl/FwZsTp

Comment: Integrals are not solved, they are evaluated, computed, ... To solve, need to say solve it what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), with $g(x)=\sin x$, and $$f'(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\cos x}}=-2\cdot\frac{\cos'x}{2\cdot\sqrt{\cos x}}=-2\cdot(\sqrt{\cos x})'\iff f(x)=-2\cdot\sqrt{\cos x}$$ then recognizing the expression of the [incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) in $\int f(x)g'(x)dx$